# How to use Selenium to scrape dynamic options data from a URL with a changing page source?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to use Selenium to scrape options data from the following URL: https://www.barchart.com/etfs-funds/quotes/$SPX/options?moneyness=allRows&expiration=2023-10-23-w.

The webpage has a drop-down menu for selecting different maturities, and I want to scrape data for all the available maturities. However, I've noticed that the page source seems to change dynamically after the data is loaded from JavaScript, which requests information from an external API not available if called directly.

Could someone provide a Python code example or guide me on how to use Selenium to select each maturity option from the drop-down menu, handle the dynamic page changes, and scrape the corresponding options data?

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to accomplish this task, taking into consideration the dynamic nature of the page source. Thank you in advance!

What I'm expecting is a Python code example or guidance on how to use Selenium effectively to select each maturity option from the drop-down menu, handle the dynamic page changes, and scrape the corresponding options data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.